# Open another file with split windows, and switch between them

Tags: vim

If I open vim with:
`$ vim -o a.ext b.ext`

I get a window that looks like this

```
+----------------------+
|           a          |
|                      |
| a.ext ---------------+
|           b          |
|                      |
+ b.ext ---------------+
```

Say I want to open another file, `c.ext`. So I do something like `:e c.ext` on the top panel.

```
+----------------------+
|           c          |
|                      |
| c.ext ---------------+
|           b          |
|                      |
+ b.ext ---------------+
```

But now the `a.ext` file is inaccessible, and I can't get back to it using `:n`. What is the proper way to open `c.ext` so I can get back to `a.ext` using `:n`?

Comment: You question says vim but the command that you are using indicates you are using vi. Which is it?

Comment: vim (...15 characters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your are already opening your files fine but they are in separate buffers and you need to use the `:bn` (or full `:bnext` and `:bprev`) commands to navigate to the next and previous buffers in a given pane.

Comment: Is there a way to make it loop through only files that were in that pane (not every file currently open)?

Comment: Without setting up some kind of matching system of your own using buffer labels, I don't think so. This doesn't work in your original example either. All the open files in vim are in a set of buffers that doesn't have any particular relation to the panes you have setup. Using next/prev commands cycles through the buffers. You could manually tweak this by setting up macros for specific buffers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try ':e #' which returns to the file previously opened.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you asked the following:

> Is there a way to make it loop through only files that were in that pane (not every file currently open)?

I do not think that Vim keeps track of all the buffers that a window (“pane”) has previously accessed. However, Vim is [scriptable](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#script)…

Here is an implementation that provides a version of this functionality by using [autocommands](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-intro) to record (in a [window-local variable](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#w%3avar)) which buffers have been activate in a window.

The (abbreviated) commands are:

- `:Hb` List the historical buffers for this window.
- `:Hbn[!] [N]` Switch to the Nth next historical buffer.
  (like `:bn`, but limited to the “historical” buffers of the current window)
- `:Hbp[!] [N]` Switch to the Nth previous historical buffer.
  (like `:bp`, but limited to the “historical” buffers of the current window)
- `:Hbf [N]` (“forget”) Remove the current buffer (or buffer number N) from the current window’s list of historical buffers.
  If you do not switch to another buffer for leaving and re-entering this window the current buffer will be re-added to the list of historical buffers.

The following code could be put into your `.vimrc` or in a separate file (e.g. `plugin/buffer-history/buffer-history.vim` somewhere under one of your [`runtimepath`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27runtimepath%27) directories):

```
augroup UL17179_BufferHistory
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter * call s:RecordBufEnter(0)
    " Grab WinEnter, since BufEnter is not triggered when doing
    " a bare ':split'. This also means that 'forgetting' a buffer is
    " only effective if you switch to another buffer before
    " switching away from the window.
    autocmd WinEnter * call s:RecordBufEnter(1)
augroup END

function! s:EnsureBufferHistory()
    if ! exists('w:BufferHistory')
        let w:BufferHistory = []
    endif
    return w:BufferHistory
endfunction

function! s:RecordBufEnter(w)
    let l = s:EnsureBufferHistory()
    let b = winbufnr(0)
    let i = index(l, b)
    if i >= 0
        unlet l[i]
    endif
    let l += [b]
    redraw
endfunction

function! s:ForgetBuffer(...)
    let l = s:EnsureBufferHistory()
    for b in a:000
        let b = b ? b+0 : winbufnr(0)
        let i = index(l, b)
        if i >= 0
            call remove(l, i)
        else
            try
                echohl WarningMsg
                echomsg 'Buffer' b 'not in history list.'
            finally
                echohl None
            endtry
        endif
    endfor
endfunction

function! s:ShowBuffers()
    let l = s:EnsureBufferHistory()
    for b in l
        echomsg b bufname(b)
    endfor
endfunction

function! s:HistoricalBufferNr(...)
    let  direction = a:0 >= 1 && !a:1 ? -1 : 1
    let move_count = a:0 >= 2 ? max([1, a:2]) : 1

    let current_bn = winbufnr(0)
    let historical_buffers = copy(filter(s:EnsureBufferHistory(),
                \ 'bufexists(v:val)'))
    let i = index(historical_buffers, current_bn)
    if i < 0
        let other_historical_buffers = historical_buffers
    elseif i == 0
        let other_historical_buffers = historical_buffers[1:]
    else
        let other_historical_buffers = historical_buffers[i+1:] +
                    \ historical_buffers[:i-1]
    endif

    if len(other_historical_buffers) <= 0
        try
            echohl ErrorMsg
            echomsg 'This window has no historical buffers!'
        finally
            echohl None
        endtry
        return 0
    endif
    if direction > 0
        let i = (move_count - 1) % len(other_historical_buffers)
    else
        let l = len(other_historical_buffers)
        let i = ((l - 1) * move_count ) % l
    endif
    return other_historical_buffers[i]
endfunction

" If the 1) user does not give a bang and
"        2) we run 'buffer N' (no bang) from inside the function and 
"        3) switching away from the buffer would require a bang,
" then the user will see an ugly 'Error detected while processing
" function' prefix before the usual E37 error message. Hoisting the
" 'buffer<bang> N' into the user-defined command means the user will
" just see a normal E37 message.
command! -nargs=0 -count=1 -bang -bar
            \ HistoricalBufferNext
            \ let s:new_bn = s:HistoricalBufferNr(1, <count>)
            \ | if s:new_bn | exe 'buffer<bang>' s:new_bn | endif
command! -nargs=0 -count=1 -bang -bar
            \ Hbn
            \ HistoricalBufferNext<bang> <count>
command! -nargs=0 -count=1 -bang -bar
            \ HistoricalBufferPrev
            \ let s:new_bn = s:HistoricalBufferNr(0, <count>)
            \ | if s:new_bn | exe 'buffer<bang>' s:new_bn | endif
command! -nargs=0 -count=1 -bang -bar
            \ Hbp
            \ HistoricalBufferPrev<bang> <count>
command! -nargs=* -count=0 -bar
            \ HistoricalBufferForget
            \ call s:ForgetBuffer(<count>, <f-args>)
command! -nargs=* -count=0 -bar
            \ Hbf
            \ HistoricalBufferForget <count> <args>
command! -nargs=0 -bar
            \ HistoricalBuffers
            \ call s:ShowBuffers()
command! -nargs=0 -bar
            \ Hb
            \ HistoricalBuffers
```